# Get application physical and virtual root of a ServiceStack application independent of hosting

Tags: servicestack

I have a FileSystemBlobProvider which needs to map physical to virtual paths and vice-versa. I also need access to the hostname (i need to generate a public url given an app relative path). Ideally this should be independent of hosting (Asp.Net or self-hosted).

Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only get access to the **Host** name within the context of a HTTP Request with:

```
base.Request.Headers["Host"]
```

which is also sensitive to reverse proxies. If you need it outside of this I would add a user-defined entry in your Web.config.

Depending on your use-case you can also access the Virtual and physical paths from the `IHttpRequest`:

```
base.Request.PathInfo
base.Request.ApplicationFilePath
```

Also ServiceStack includes a [VirtualFileSystem](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/IO/IVirtualPathProvider.cs) that you can access with:

```
EndpointHost.VirtualPathProvider
```

Which you can query to get the virtual and physical path of the root directory where ServiceStack is located:

```
EndpointHost.VirtualPathProvider.RootDirectory.VirtualPath
EndpointHost.VirtualPathProvider.RootDirectory.RealPath
```

Comment: Thanks Demis. I ended up using EndpointHost.VirtualPathProvider. BTW - is it reliable to use ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory.GetBaseUrl() to try to determine Host Name ?

Comment: It's not 100%, it first looks at `Config.WebHostUrl` and if that's not set it looks for the `ApplicationBaseUrl` that gets populated from the first HTTP Request. This is sensitive to how the first request was made, e.g. aliases/virtual hosts/reverse proxies/etc. My recommendation is to set `Config.WebHostUrl` manually.

Comment: I just opted for a setting in my config file. Thanks.